# View not found for sending email with laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, email

I'm trying to send an email with Laravel (5.4) but still getting this error:

> InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php line 137:
>   View [mails.forgot] not found.
>
> ---
>
> at FileViewFinder->findInPaths('mails.forgot', array('{my app dir}/resources/views'))
> in FileViewFinder.php line 79
>
> ---
>
> at FileViewFinder->find('mails.forgot')
> in Factory.php line 128
>
> ---
>
> at Factory->make('mails.forgot', array('emailAddress' => null, 'connection' => null, 'queue' => null, 'delay' => null, 'message' => object(Message)))
> in Mailer.php line 286

Added the file in `resources/views/mails/forgot.blade.php`

In the controller:

```
Mail::to('test@gmail.com')->send(new ForgotEmail());
```

In the mail file (Mail/ForgotEmail.php) I call:

```
return $this->view('mails.forgot');
```

For the rest of my app views are working correctly.

Comment: Have you ran composer dump-autoload to see if this helps?

Comment: Can you manually view `mails.forget`, like in a Route, such as `Route::get("/test", function(){ return view("mails.forgot"); });`, followed by navigating to `myapp.com/test`

Comment: dump-autoload didn't help.. @TimLewis Nice tip, that gives me the same error.. so it seems the reason is not the mailable.

Comment: My routing normally looks like this: Route::post('register/confirm', 'UserController@sendConfirmationEmail');

Comment: Yup; Routing should use Controller methods, but for quick reference you can use a `function` to mimic one. And yeah, if you can't return it manually, there's something else up, though, at a glance, I can't see it. `mails.forgot` seems to be the right key to access it...

Comment: Seems I can only access the views from the controllers .. :(

Answer (score 0):

Clean Laravels caché by issuing either `php artisan cache:clear` or `php artisan config:cache` see if that works...

Comment: That fixed my problem! I already executed the commands locally but it didn't take effect. Had to run it directly on my vagrant box. Now it works :)

Comment: @Dennis Glad it worked out, please select my answer as the accepted one :)

Answer (score 0):

On my specific case, the my template filename was `user.new.blade.php`

It would not work. I renamed it to `usernew.blade.php` and now it works. Seems like there cannot be extra dots in the filename